# <Identifier> Expected:

Tags: java, arrays, identifier

I'm getting an error on this line, about how my array is imported into my JUNIT.

```
package test123;
import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import java.util.*;

        public class mainJUNIT
           {
            main2.array.length();

            @Test
            public ArrayList<Integer> test (ArrayList<Integer> N)
            {   
            ...
            }
```

My error is flagging my `main2.array.length();` I have absolutely no idea why.

```
`javac main2.java mainJUNIT.java
mainJUNIT.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
    main2.array.length();
                      ^`
```

Any advice? I'm stuck. I can't get rid of this at all. I'm sure it's something stupidly easy, but I can't figure it out. main2 is another java class (main2.java) that I'm trying to get the array from.

Comment: What do you think that line should do and why do you think so? Note that I'm not asking what you want it to do.

Comment: Please post the full class definition, and apply correct indentation. Skip irrelevant methods, but not closing braces for relevant code. what is main2?

Comment: Haha I'm sorry... main2 is another Java class I have. This class is supposed to refer that class. I don't understand what happened, it was properly formatted until submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `main2.array.length();` in your class is not in any method, therefore you cannot call the method.

Also, the length in array is a `field` not a `method`, therefore `main2.array.length()` should be `main2.array.length` (returns an int).

Your call to `length` should be assigned to a variable:

for example:

package test123;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class mainJUNIT
{
    int length = main2.array.length;

    @Test
    public ArrayList<Integer> test (ArrayList<Integer> N)
    {   
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried it both ways and continued to still have trouble. Any ideas? It throws the same error every time.